# cut-edges, cycles, and a 2 connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Read this statement in a textbook:

If G - e - f is disconnected, then f is a cut-edge in G-e, whence f belongs to no edges in G-e, and thus every cycle in G containing f must contain also e.

How can this be true? If f is a cut-edge in G-e, how can f belong to no edges in G-e? Why would every cycle in G containing f must also contain e

Comment: I wonder if '$f$ belongs to no edges in $G-e$' should read '$f$ belongs to no cycles in $G-e$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it meant to say $f$ belongs to no cycles in $G-e$.

Comment: Ok. That seems reasonable. But why would every cycle containing f must also contain e?

Comment: If $f$ existed on a cycle that didn't include $e$, could $f$ be a cut-edge in $G-e$?

Comment: sure, why not? I don't see any reason why not. I get the feeling the answer to your question is supposed to be obvious. But I don't see it.

Comment: If $f$ existed on a cycle that didn't include $e$, then $f$ would exist on a cycle in $G-e$ and so $f$ could not disconnect $G-e$, which contradicts the fact that $G-e-f$ is disconnected.

Comment: Why is this true: " 
If f existed on a cycle that didn't include e, then f would exist on a cycle in G−e "?

Comment: So $f$ exists on a cycle that doesn't include $e$. Does the removal of $e$ destroy that cycle? $e$ is not a part of the cycle, and so the removal of $e$ does not disturb this cycle and so the cycle exists in $G-e$.

Comment: Isn't connectivity fun? I don't know how many hours I put into trying to get my head wrapped around all of this.